# How do I get a function to paste data while eliminating any trailing blank cells?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I've got a function here that seems to work sometimes, and other times it refuses to work and treats the ranges that I feed as if they don't exist. I need this function to paste data from a source (table column) to a target (another table column), whilst eliminating any trailing blanks. There are going to be blanks within the data being copied, so the function must only eliminate blanks that at the end.

```
Function Paste_Col_Data_No_Trail(strSrcTbl As String, strSrcCol As String, strTarTbl As String, strTarCol As String)
    Dim rngSrc As Range
    Dim rngTar As Range

    Set rngSrc = Range(strSrcTbl).ListObject.ListColumns(strSrcCol).DataBodyRange
    Set rngTar = Range(strTarTbl).ListObject.ListColumns(strTarCol).DataBodyRange

    For i = rngSrc.Count To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(rngSrc(i)) = False Then
            Range(rngSrc(1), rngSrc(i)).Copy
'This line is where the error is being thrown
            rngTar(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues           
            i = 1
        End If
    Next i   
End Function
```

This code has worked for most executions, but now it's inexplicably throwing 1004 errors. To my understanding, that would mean that the ranges that I've used (rngSrc and rngTar) are no longer being recognized.

Comment: Instead of passing the function `String`s, why not pass it `ListColumn` objects?

Comment: Also - `Range(rngSrc(1), rngSrc(i)).Copy` could be problematic. Best practice is to qualify which `Worksheet` the `Range` is on.

Comment: Would filtering out the blanks and copying visible cells accomplish what you want?

Comment: @BigBen
- I mostly used the notation that I did to save the amount of variables that were being passed to the Function (out of laziness). It would require that I name the sheet, table, and column as opposed to just the table and column. I will give that way a try though.
- Filtering out blanks wouldn't work as some of the records to have blank fields. Probably not the best database practice, but I thought I may be able to code my way around that.

Comment: If you switch to a `ListColumn` object, your function should only have *two* parameters: `srcCol As ListColumn` and `tarCol As ListColumn`. No need to pass table or sheet names :)

Comment: @BigBen - Would you declare that as a public variable outside the function in that case?

Comment: Nope. You would specify the `ListColumn`s in question when you call the function.